# Getting UrlGenerationErrorr when trying to run test

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ajax, testunit

> 1) Error:
>   SummariesControllerTest#test_should_get_edit:
>   ActionController::UrlGenerationError: No route matches {:action=>"edit", :controller=>"summaries", :summary=>"298486374", :summary_id=>"298486374"}
>       test/controllers/summaries_controller_test.rb:23:in `block in '

this is is the test causing the error

```
test "should update summary" do
  xhr :patch, :udpate, id: @summary.id, summary: { text: @summary.text }
  assert_response :success
end
```

the controller action:

```
 def update
  @listing = Listing.find(summary_params[:listing_id])
  @summary = Summary.find(params[:id])
  @summary.update_attributes(listing_id: summary_params[:listing_id], text: summary_params[:text], id: params[:id])
end
```

and the routes:

```
Rails.application.routes.draw do
  resources :listings
  resources :summaries
  resources :highlights
end
```

[image]

the route is there, the action is also there yet the error appears, does anybody see my mistake? Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have a typo (in the word "update"):

```
xhr :patch, :udpate, id: @summary.id, summary: { text: @summary.text }
```

should be:

```
xhr :patch, :update, id: @summary.id, summary: { text: @summary.text }
```

Comment: hey thank you for the response, that was a good catch but it did not fix the error. do you have another idea? it is the same error

Comment: Post the full stacktrace and the output of `rake routes`

Comment: there is the rake routes, there is really no full stacktrace, the error is all it gives me.

Comment: @JavierPerez Are you sure that's the test that is throwing the error? I see `test_should_get_edit` in the pasted output.

Answer (score 0):

```
test "should update summary" do
  xhr :patch, :udpate, id: @summary.id, summary: { text: @summary.text }
  assert_response :success
end
```

Hey thank you for the responses, there was no problem with the routes, but I did have to pass id: @summary.id as it needed that for the listing. I changed the test and it passed.